# Google Chrome is showing the date format yyyy-MM-dd instead of dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, date-format, html-input

The specified value `"18/08/2017"` does not conform to the required format, `yyyy-MM-dd`

Google Chrome doesn't load date in `dd/MM/yyyy` format from the controller method.  I want to load date into date type field. google chrome gives me a warning. How do I fix this

The specified value `"18/08/2017"` does not conform to the required format, `yyyy-MM-dd`.

here is my code in the view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateReceived, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", 
    new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type="date" } })
```

Comment: I would have left input type as text and use some jquery plugin to select date, as date input type shows datepicker only in chrome and doesn't work in other browser.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome wants "yyyy-MM-dd" -> 2017/08/18 
You gave chrome "dd-MM-yyyy" -> 18/08/2017  
You need to give Chrome the format it wants.

Change to:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateReceived, "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type="date" } })
```

Comment: Still not working. I changed it as @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateReceived, "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) and DisplayFormat also same in modal

Answer (score 0):

Please write the below javascript in your page

```
<script type="text/jscript">   
    $(function () {
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            if ($.browser.webkit) {

                //ES - Chrome does not use the locale when new Date objects instantiated:
                var d = new Date();

                return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
            }
            else {

                return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
            }
        };
    });
```

and in view write this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateReceived, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", 
 new { @class = "form-control" })
```